# Dropdown menu doesnt work

Tags: php, zend-framework, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to limit 1 option in the dropdown menu by calling `Zend_Auth` to get the username of the user logged in. The code seems fine, but it only displays 1 blank space in the dropdown menu.

```
    $auth= Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $user= $auth->getIdentity();
    $username   = $user->username;

    $memberid = $this->createElement('select', 'memberid'); //dropdown menu of member name
    $memberid->setLabel('Member Id')
    ->setRequired(true);
    $db_member = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();

    $select = $db_member->select('userid')
    ->from(array('usertable'))
    ->where('usertable.username = ?', $username);     

    $row = $db_member->fetchRow($select);
    $memberid->addMultiOption($row['userid']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `addMultiOption` takes two parameters: $option and $value, so instead of

```
$memberid->addMultiOption($row['userid']);
```

try to make something like

```
$memberid->addMultiOption('user_id', $row['userid']);
```

Where `user_id` is a name of the option element.

Also I advise you to make separate forms and models and not to write DB and forms code in controllers

And also, why are you making the query to database to retrieve the user_id? You can get user_id just form `auth` object.

```
$user_id = $user->id;
```

Comment: Noted with thanks. However the drop down box now displays a userid of '1' instead of '30' which is supposed to be the right id for my user.

Comment: It's okay, got it fix. 
$select = $db_member->select() << caused the problem
Thanks anyway :)